Could not compile `pyth-solana-receiver-sdk` (lib) due to 4 previous errors
I have build problem with the pyth-solana-receiver-sdk basic example.
It is a single file lib.rs program running on WSL2.
Cargo (anchor) build fails with this error:
6 | #[account]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`, found `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`
  |
  = note: expected signature `fn() -> anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
             found signature `fn() -> solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `account` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

All the components and versions are updated to the latest.

avm 0.30.0
solana-cli 1.18.23 (src:aeb3a2e1; feat:4215500110, client:SolanaLabs)
cargo 1.81.0 (2dbb1af80 2024-08-20)
rustc 1.81.0 (eeb90cda1 2024-09-04)
anchor-cli 0.30.1
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.18.23
platform-tools v1.41
rustc 1.75.0

Cargo dependencies. The same issue with sdk "0.1.0".
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
solana-program = "2.0.10"
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.1"

Diagnostic message:


After a while i found a problem with multiple dependendencies of 'solana_program' crate. Check them by running cargo tree -i solana-program. In my case it was 2.0.10 and 1.18.23. For some reason v2 is not in a good relationship with 'pythnet-sdk'. So you can try to downgrade it like this.
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
solana-program = "< 2.0"
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.1"
pythnet-sdk = "=2.1.0"

Or simply let the automatic dependency resolver do the job for you. The strict version of 'pythnet-sdk' should be enough.
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
pyth-solana-receiver-sdk = "0.3.1"
pythnet-sdk = "=2.1.0"

